# Openerp calculate qty and date listing

Tags: reporting, odoo

I am very new to openerp, and have been given a task. My firts question which sounds silly is, how can I stirp datefield to just a month on openerp. 2. with the code below am trying to get a balance of water in reservoirs basically calculating from water meter in - meter out to get balance this has to work like a quantity in stock control

```
def _water_balance(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
    res = {}
    bal = 0.0
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        for traject in rec.trajectory_ids:
            trajectory_balance = self.pool.get('supply.trajectory').browse(cr, uid, traject.id , context=context).trajectory_balance
            bal += float(trajectory_balance)
        res[rec.id] = bal
    return res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get month from datetime field using strftime function like,

```
month = datetimefield.strftime("%m") # Month of the datetimefield
month = datetime.now().strftime("%m") # Current month
```

Just changed few code try following,

```
def _water_balance(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
    res = {}
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[rec.id] = 0.00
        bal = 0.0
        for traject in rec.trajectory_ids:
            bal += float(traject.trajectory_balance)
        res[rec.id] = bal
    return res
```

Comment: @Carlos- great! keep it up.